# Webpack: Modify source before generating source maps

Tags: webpack, source-maps, terser

I'm using Webpack 4, [SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/) and [terser-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin).

The problem is that I need to also modify the minified JS-bundles – inject specific code to the beginning of file. The mutation is made using custom webpack plugin that takes an asset source string, prepends it with my code and creates a new RawSource. And this is what obviously breaks source maps mapping. If I remove the mutation part then everything works fine.

The key point here is to made this mutation **after minification** but **before generating** the source maps, while Terser makes this at the same time as I understood.

Is this possible with the current stack that I use?

Terser config:

```js
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            terserOptions: {
                mangle: true,
                ecma: 6,
                compress: {
                    inline: 1,
                    pure_funcs: ['Set', 'Map'],
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
},
```

SourceMapDevToolPlugin config:

```js
plugins: [
    new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].map',
        publicPath: 'https://my-custom-url.net/source-maps/',
    }),
],
```

Comment: Meet with the same problem.